# jig-saw puzzle is not working in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, mozilla

i am try to create puzzle. It is working only in chrome and safari. but when i run in firefox or internet explorer it is not working. kindly tell me the solution for this problem.

I've used this library

```
http://code.google.com/p/jq-jigsaw-puzzle/
```

I tried mask in firefox still it is not working.

Comment: The JavaScript library at the link you supplied only creates puzzles that work in webkit browsers, chrome and safari.

Comment: there is any other option to run in firefox or IE

Comment: no, because '-webkit-mask-image' css property is currently only supported in webkit browsers.

Comment: Firefox is not a webkit browser. Hence this problem, as its not compatible with the mentioned library.

Answer (score 1):

jqJigsawPuzzle is a javascript library that lets you create jigsaw puzzles in your web pages. It requres jQuery and jQuery UI to be included along with jqJigsawPuzzle. At the moment it only works in webkit browsers since it uses the CSS property '-webkit-mask-image'.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation

```
Download the last version, see a live demo (only compatible with webkit browsers) or install the Chrome App.
```